# how to use css control multi nest div and each of them can scroll

Tags: html, css

I have a three level menu to show on mobile, when I click the first menu title, show the second menu list,when I click the second menu title, show the third menu lists;
when I click the first menu title, I add the `no-display` class on it, because is don't work in some browser on Android if I don't add the `no-display` class,but the problem is it don't work only in iphone6
the structure is:

```css
       .brand-selector {
         position: fixed;
         top: 3.5em;
         left: 0;
         right: 0;
         bottom: 0;
         height: 100%;
         overflow: scroll;
         z-index: 10;
         background: #ffffff;
         padding-bottom: 7.5em;
       }
       .brand-selector .brand-item.active {
         position: fixed;
         top: 3.5em;
         left: 0;
         right: 0;
         bottom: 0;
         height: 100%;
         overflow: scroll;
         z-index: 10;
         background: #ffffff;
         padding-bottom: 7.5em;
       }
       .brand-selector .brand-item.active .auto-series {
         display: block;
         overflow: scroll;
       }
       .no-display {
         overflow: hidden;
       }
       ul li {
         list-style-type: none;
       }
```

```html
<ul id="brand_selector" class="brand-selector">
  <li class="brand-item active">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="brand-link font-ml active no-display">
      <div class="figure">
        <img src="http://7xj3c4.com2.z0.glb.qiniucdn.com/car_brand_33" alt="Audi">
        <p class="title">Audi</p>
      </div>
    </a>

    <ul class="auto-series on">
      <li class="auto-series-item active">
        <a href="javascript:;" data-id="3304" class="auto-series-link">AudiQ4</a>
        <ul class="auto-type">
          <li class="auto-type-item atomic">
            <a href="javascript:;" class="auto-type-link" data-id="17821">AudiQ4 2014</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="auto-series-item">
        <a href="javascript:;" data-id="19" class="auto-series-link">AudiA4</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What is your problem? Why don't you show us the javascript code? Can you provide a working jsfiddle?

Comment: height:100% of what ? your CSS has no reference to calculate this. i guess you mean viewport. so take it from html via body all the way down to your element. or use coordonates to set the size of your absolute/fixed element :)